# How to take the values form multiple select that works with each?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, node.js

I'm working in a program and i need to take the value from multiple select. The problem is that my view is a .hbs file and the multiple select is with {each}. Look at it yourself:

First i render and export a variable (links)

```
router.get('/contactsemail', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const link = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM links WHERE user_id=?', [req.user.id]);
    console.log(link);
    res.render('links/contactsemail', { link });
});
```

And i render this view:

```
<div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
            <form action="/links/contactsend" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Tria els contactes a qui vols enviar el missatge</label>
                    <select  class="form-control" name="contacts" multiple>

                        {{#each link}}

                        <option>{{title}}</option>

                        {{/each}}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"><br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                        envia
                    </button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now i need to know the values that the user has chosen but I need that the values are separated because if i take the values like that the result is this: 
[image: i make a console.log of the select]

i make a console.log of the select

But, is the result is this i can't take more information about the links from my database. I don't know how i can make this, please help me!

And I have another question, how can I make a textarea in which images can be pasted in?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to access the select in view .hbs file then you can do by the following way

```
<select  class="form-control" name="contacts" multiple>

       {{#each link}}

         <option {{ title }}>{{title}}</option>

        {{/each}}
</select>
```

Now you can excess that option which is selected by the user. I hope it will help you to figure out your problem.